# how can i override cache "get" method laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-cache

I would like to override the method `get()` of the class `Illuminate\Cache\Repository` as :

```
<?php
namespace App\Illuminate\Cache;

use Illuminate\Cache\Repository as BaseRepository;

class Repository extends BaseRepository{

    public function get($key)
    {
        // changes
    }
}
```

**But I don't know how to tell Laravel to load my class instead of the original one.**

is there any way to do this ?

---

### edit 1

I have created a `macro()` but it only works if the method does not exist in the `BaseRepository`, for example:

**this dosnt work**

```php
use Illuminate\Cache;

Cache\Repository::macro('get',function (){
    return 'hi';
});
```

**However, this worked:**

```php
use Illuminate\Cache;

Cache\Repository::macro('newName',function (){
    return 'hi';
});
```

so `macro` can't do it because  `Laravel::macro()` is creating a new function but doesn't override

Answer (score 1):

When you are making new cache objects it's easy to make an instance from your class, not the BaseRepository class.

But when Laravel's service container is building the object (Or with dependency injection) you have to bind your extended class as the main class in the appServiceProvider.

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Cache\Repository as BaseRepository;
use App\Illuminate\Cache\Repository;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(BaseRepository::class, function ($app) {
            return $app->make(Repository::class);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

But you have to pass an implementation of \Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Store to the Repository's constructor.

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;    
use Illuminate\Cache\Repository as BaseRepository;
use App\Repository;
use Illuminate\Cache\ArrayStore;


class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(BaseRepository::class,function($app){
            return $app->make(Repository::class,['store'=>$app->make(ArrayStore::class)]);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi again. Can you explain more about the situation? Does it return an error? Yeah, I know it doesn't work because you have to take care of passing one of the \Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Store implementations as a dependency in the Repository class.
For example, I added how to make a cache repository class with ArrayStore to the end of my answer.

Comment: hi @mahmood-moradian , Thank you.. unfortunately The redis driver will not read from the new method **"I tried `dd($key)` "**, but when I try dd($key) from the base method, I get the keys from the redis driver