# Laravel Cache: Multiple Redis drivers hit the same key and it takes time

Tags: php, laravel, redis, laravel-8, laravel-cache

[image: Cache . Multiple Redis drivers hit the same key and it takes time]

As you can see in the image here, I am calling the same key multiple times in the same request.

In each case, it takes `0.16` or even `0.26` milliseconds. As a result, we will see that even if the caches on the same key are many, it will take quite some time

So I was trying something, if I could override the method `get()` of `Illuminate\Cache\Repository` as in this: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68686644/7511165)

I will be able to put any keys that already have been hitted in a php array in a custom class `CacheHandler`, for example:

```php
namespace App\Lib\CacheHandler;

class CacheHandler
{
    public $stats = [];

    /**
     * @param $key
     * @param $value
     */
    public function setStats($key, $value): void
    {
        $this->stats[$key] = $value;
    }

    /**
     * @param $key
     * @return mixed|null
     */
    public function getStats($key)
    {
        //return $this->stats[$key];
        //return $this->stats[$key] ?? null; // can't make `nothingHere` as null  because  stats[$key] = null
        return $this->stats[$key] ?? 'nothingHere'; // can't make `nothingHere` as null  because  stats[$key] = null
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any idea, if anyone has one, please share it.

Comment: I would firstly **NEVER** override any core class/method unless advised on the documentation. Secondly, it is 260 Microsenconds... 0.26.... it is okay... Try to find other roadblocks related to performance before trying to do this non recommendable thing.

Comment: @matiaslauriti As you point out, it is only *260 Microseconds*, but if we consider that there are a lot of caches in this `per 1 request` , it will take some time, so I believe we shouldn't hit the cache more than once per request.

Comment: That would mean to create a class, as you said, that will handle this, if it is in the class itself, use it, else go to the cache, not edit the cache core code to do this... This layer should be done in other part... Where do you want to implement this ?

Comment: yes my dear @matiaslauriti , that's exactly what i want to do, but i don't know how exactly ,,So I thought it should something like Overriding the `get()` method

Comment: I understand, again, no, because you are overriding a core class, that is a no-no. Share more info, like where do you consume this cache all the time, is this an API ? What else do you have as a layer ? Do you consume any local service class to get data ?